# Replace ' " in PHP

Tags: php, str-replace

An interesting question about str_replace.

Here's the example:

```
$search  = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
$replace = array('B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');
$subject = 'A';
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
```

What if I want to replace '" into something else, say -. How do I do that?

The problem is I can't write something like this

```
$search  = array(''"', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
$replace = array('-', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');
$subject = 'A';
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
```

Any solution?

Comment: The question isn't that interesting. You just need to escape the single quote of you are using it in single quotes, or escape the double quote if you are using it in double quotes.

Comment: It's interesting to him.

Comment: I agree with the comment right above. It even says on http://stackoverflow.com/faq: "Be nice. Treat others with the same respect you'd want them to treat you." A very good rule, I think, and one you should try and follow not only on this site but in life in general. Also, we were all beginners once. Nobody expects a pupil to be able to read the first day in school. I don't think you should expect a budding programmer to know things before he or she do either.

Answer (score 7):

```
$search  = array('\'"', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
```

Single-quoted strings have two escapes, `\'` for `'` and `\\` for `\`.

Comment: @Eric Sim: You can escape characters in any string anywhere in PHP code.